Expression Engine Entries Loop Index
Does Expression Engine entries loop have a variable to show which index you're on for each iteration? I found the {count} and {total_results} in the docs, but cant seem to find the variable that spits out the index of the iteration. Does EE even have one?
I know I could do this by turning on PHP and using PHP to give me the index number, but i'm trying to avoid using PHP.

This might be a better question to ask at: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/? Information hovering the expressionengine tag seems to suggest.
